# Discord js Giveaway command with join server requirement

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a giveaway command for my bot with server requirement
The members reaction should not be added if he didn't join the given server.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible, to stop reaction being added, but you can easily remove it using [reaction.users.remove(UserResolvable)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager?scrollTo=remove). So do something as

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd",(reaction,user) => {
    if (/*test if the message is giveaway*/) {
        if (!/*user is in the guild*/) {
            reaction.users.remove(user);
        }
    }
})
```

.